# What is the default openSUSE Rescue login?

Tags: login, opensuse, rescue

On booting the Rescue System from an openSUSE DVD, I find myself at a "rescue login" prompt:

[image: rescue login]

What are the default login details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rescue login:` text is a login prompt expecting you to type in a username.  Enter `root` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that should give you a `root` shell. If it asks you for a password, you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Further reading: https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/single-html/book.opensuse.startup/index.html#sec.trouble.data.recover.rescue